# adding room dependency gives manifest merge error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-room

After adding

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1"
```

to my gradle file, I am getting below. Any clue how this can be fixed? I tried adding tools:replace="android:value" but it crash my app.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the version **26.1.0** of the support libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the conflicting dependency like:

```
implementation("android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
}
```

and the error was gone.